# cannot show in data from database in edittext

Tags: java, database

i am making a form FVPI.java. in the form i'm taking data from database but cannot show in form. this is source code form FVPI.java. please help..

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fvpi, null);
      dataSource = new DBDataSource(getActivity());
      dataSource.open();

      edtsales= (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.txtsales);
      edttglpros= (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.txttgl);
      edtnamacustomer= (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.txtnamacustomer);
      edtalamat= (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.txtalamat);
      edtarea= (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.txtarea);
      edtcp= (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.txtcp);
      edtnotelp= (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.txtphone);
      edtemail= (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.txtemail);
      edtowner= (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.txtowner);
      edtdirector= (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.txtdirector);
      edtgroupcompany= (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.txtgroupcompany);

        Customer customer = dataSource.getCustomer(customerid);
        if(Globals.customerpros==null){
            Globals.customerpros=customer;
        }
        edtnamacustomer.setText(customer.getname());
        edtalamat.setText(customer.getAddress());
        edtarea.setText(customer.getArea());
        edtcp.setText(customer.getContactperson());
        edtnotelp.setText(customer.getPhoneno());
        edtemail.setText(customer.getCustomeremail());
        edtowner.setText(customer.getOwner());
        edtdirector.setText(customer.getDirector());
        edtgroupcompany.setText(customer.getGroupcompany());
        edkapasitaspros.setText(customer.getCapacity());
```

and this is DBdatasource.java

```
public Customer getCustomer(String customerid){
        Customer Customer = new Customer();
        Cursor cursor = database.query(DBHelper.CUSTOMER, allCustomer, DBHelper.CUSTOMER_ID +"='cus1' ", null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        Customer = cursorToCustomer(cursor);
        cursor.close();
        return Customer;
    }

    private Customer cursorToCustomer(Cursor cursor)
    {
        Customer Customer = new Customer();
        Log.v("info", "The getString "+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CUSTOMER_ID)));
        Log.v("info", "The setLatLng " +cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.NAME))+","
                                       +cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.ADDRESS))+","
                                       +cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.AREA))+","
                                       +cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CONTACT_PERSON))+","
                                       +cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.PHONE_NO))+","
                                       +cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CUSTOMER_EMAIL))+","
                                       +cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.OWNER))+","
                                       +cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.DIRECTOR))+","
                                       +cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.GROUP_COMPANY))+","
                                       +cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CAPACITY)));
        Customer.setcustomerid(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CUSTOMER_ID)));
        Customer.setname(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.NAME)));
        Customer.setAddress(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.ADDRESS)));
        Customer.setCity(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CITY)));
        Customer.setZipcode(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.ZIPCODE)));
        Customer.setArea(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.AREA)));
        Customer.setContactperson(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CONTACT_PERSON)));
        Customer.setPhoneno(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.PHONE_NO)));
        Customer.setMobileno(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.MOBILE_NO)));
        Customer.setCustomeremail(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CUSTOMER_ID)));
        Customer.setOwner(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.OWNER)));
        Customer.setDirector(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.DIRECTOR)));
        Customer.setGroupcompany(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.GROUP_COMPANY)));
        Customer.setCapacity(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CAPACITY)));
        Customer.setOrderestimate(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.ORDERESTIMATE)));
        Customer.setComplainer(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COMPLAINER)));
        return Customer;
    }
```

and this error in log cat

```
03-04 09:53:01.805: V/info(7604): The getString cus1
03-04 09:53:01.805: V/info(7604): The setLatLng toko maju jaya,alam sutera,Banten,Warda,02153120019,toko@gmail.com,warda,warda,IMS Group,1000
03-04 09:53:01.805: W/dalvikvm(7604): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41610450)
03-04 09:53:01.815: E/AndroidRuntime(7604): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-04 09:53:01.815: E/AndroidRuntime(7604): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-04 09:53:01.815: E/AndroidRuntime(7604):     at ims.app.mobileorder.FVPI.onCreateView(FVPI.java:151)
03-04 09:53:01.815: E/AndroidRuntime(7604):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
03-04 09:53:01.815: E/AndroidRuntime(7604):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way (the changes are marked)
BTW instanciating a new object and naming it the same thing as the class itself is not good practice, may lead to major errors along the way

The main problem in your code was that and the fact that you were receiving a String called "customerid" but in your cursor you search for this "cus1"

```
public Customer getCustomer(String customerid){
    Customer customer = new Customer();  //<--
    Cursor cursor = database.query(DBHelper.CUSTOMER, allCustomer, DBHelper.CUSTOMER_ID +"=" + customerid, null, null, null, null); //<--
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    customer = cursorToCustomer(cursor); //<--
    cursor.close();
    return customer; //<--
}
```

Comment: i've try this one but still nothing happened. any other sugested??

Comment: Are you sure you changed this line Cursor cursor = database.query(DBHelper.CUSTOMER, allCustomer, DBHelper.CUSTOMER_ID +"=" + customerid, null, null, null, null); like a said?

Comment: it's the samae. i have used the method but nothing happened.

Comment: I would advise you on debuging your code with breakpoints to make sure everything is as it should be because i tried the code i showed you and if everything else on your program is correct then this part should also be because it is working well in my test program